# All compatible games crash on Windows 8 via Bootcamp

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, boot-camp, macbook-air

I'm running Windows 8 x64 natively via bootcamp on a brand new Macbook Air 2013. However, I've run into a small problem: every game that I try to start up crashes instantly.

To attempt to correct the issue, I went through the following steps:

- Installed the Boot Camp helper tools during Windows 8 installation
- Installed the most recent drivers for the Intel HD 5000 integrated graphics using the Intel Driver Update Utility (http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect)
- Ran `dxdiag`, no problems were reported

I have played all of the games (for example, Age of Empires II HD and Halo CE) before on other Windows 8 systems without a problem.

I am not sure if this is related or not, but if I right click on the desktop and select "Graphics Properties", a dialog pops up that says "GfxUIEx has stopped working".

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the graphics driver and running a game?

Comment: I just tried doing so actually- and the game works! (albeit it functions oddly than normally). Why would this be?

Comment: I re-installed the driver and the games don't work again. Shouldn't the opposite result be occurring?

Comment: I dont know much about about Macs and BootCamp.  However, you are making a bunch of assumptions:  1) that you should use other drivers 2) the intel driver is correct/supported 3) that you should be using an OEM driver, not the manufacturer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, Windows 8.1 is not currently compatible with the latest Intel HD 5000 drivers! I probably should have mentioned that fact.

I was able to fix the issue completely by installing the beta drivers for Windows 8.1, more information here: http://techau.com.au/intel-hd-5000-driver-issues-with-windows-8-1/.

I then downloaded the drivers from here: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Intel-Releases-Iris-and-HD-Graphics-Driver-Version-9-18-10-3214-367506.shtml

Comment: So I got this and the games are working, but a game engine I use Leadwerks isn't. I'm confused as to why this is beta but the version is lower than the current version out that doesn't work.